# How to return only the integer part of a decimal value from a SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.8

I need to return only the integer part of a number I received through an http request from a SQL Server view.

For example, if a number inside a database is 1234, I need to receive the value 1234, but the ASP.NET framework returns 1234.0.

The zero after the decimal point is my problem.

Despite my column being in decimal format, all saved values ​​are integers. I can't change the column datatype of this view.

My view is composed only by two columns:

```
PERSON_CODE (decimal(6,0), null)
PERSON_NAME (varchar(115), null)
```

I've already tried to format using `[DisplayFormat(...`, but it makes no difference, my returned value always has the 0 after the decimal point.

```
public class VW_PERSONS
{
    [Key]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:0}")]
    public decimal PERSON_CODE { get; set; }

    public string PERSON_NAME { get; set; }
}
```

My controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public object GetPersonByCode(decimal PERSON_CODE)
{
    try
    {
        return new Business.Person().GetPersonByCode(PERSON_CODE);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, Util.GetExceptionMessages(ex)));
    }
}
```

Inside my business:

```
internal PersonModel GetPersonByCode(string PERSON_CODE)
{
    using (ExtranetEntities extranet = new ExtranetEntities())
    {
        int CODE_PERSON = int.Parse(PERSON_CODE);

        return new ContatoModel(extranet.VW_PERSONS.FirstOrDefault(r => r.PERSON_CODE == CODE_PERSON));
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.floor?view=net-6.0

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is, if there is any. `The zero after the decimal point is my problem` no it's not. Trailing decimal zeroes aren't significant - that's math. How you display them is entirely up to your application/your code. There's absolutely nothing wrong with returning `123.0` in a JSON response - it's exactly the same number as `123`. *Unless* you really wanted an integer type instead of a decimal. In that case, `PERSON_CODE` should be a `int` or `long`, not a `decimal`

Comment: In fact, why is a `PERSON_CODE` database field a `decimal` instead of an `int` or `bigint` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The problem is that the PERSON_CODE is used as a primary key. 
I'm anticipating problems when the system assigns 1234.0 in its variable instead of 1234, this could cause null return due to the literal difference between the expected (1234) and the real (1234.0).  
Programmers before me did this (field as decimal), because there are PERSON_NAME`s with more than one PERSON_CODE, so in this case there would be 1234.1, 1234.2... But never 1234.0

Comment: In that case you have a serious database design bug. This is neither a C# nor a SQL Server bug. If `1234.1` is an acceptable value, your view can't return a `numeric(6,0)` without causing duplicates. That design bug though means that you have to accept the decimals, precisely because they *are* valid values. `But never 1234.0` quite the opposite, this is a perfectly valid value. Decimals aren't strings and the integer `1234` is actually `1234.0` as a `numeric(6,1)`

Comment: If you want to serialize those decimals in a non-standard way you'll have to write a [custom JSON converter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) that checks for a fractional part and emits a string without decimals if there's no fractional part. You can get the fractional part with `value % 1.0m`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cast in your sql query

CAST(decimal value as INT)

And you should change the property(person_code) to int as well.

Comment: Where should that code be implemented? In the DB or in the .NET-code? Apart from this doing **both** - casting **and** changing the db-type is useless. **Either** cast or change the type